# Visual Studio Toolbar button to parse open file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'd like to make a visual studio extension with a button that can read the content of the selected, open file in Visual Studio.
Creating the template of the extension is easy and fine. How do I get to the contents of the open and selected file in Visual Studio please?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though does require saving the document first.

```
DocumentView docView = await VS.Documents.GetActiveDocumentViewAsync();
if (docView?.TextView == null) return; //not a text window
ITextDocument doc = docView.TextBuffer?.GetTextDocument();
doc?.Save();
string filePath = docView?.FilePath;
string fileContents = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
{
    fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```